# Which version of xcode install on lion

Tags: xcode, osx-lion

Which version of xcode install on lion ? i use 4.0.2 but doesn't install and says should install snow leopard 10.6.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need XCode 4.1 for Lion.

Message when running XCode 4.2:

> Xcode 4.2 requires Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard
>
> Install the Xcode Tools version that supports Mac OS X 10.7 Lion.

If you have 4.2 on Lion run this:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all
```

Comment: The "uninstall-devtools" got me going again, but I then had to reinstall via the installer since the App Store still thought I had XCode installed:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777462/xcode-4-1-cant-reinstall-app-store-says-installed

Comment: The accepted answer is dated.  Xcode up to 4.6 should be okay with lion 10.7.5  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Versions_compare_table

Answer (score 2):

How about the latest? Xcode 4.1

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using the beta version (registered developers only) you have to get the version of XCode from the Mac App Store which is 4.1. That is the only version that will work with Lion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install directly from the App Store, not from the install disc.